# Routing Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the next prefix

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{slug}', 'namespace' => 'User'], function ()
```

And I have some routes as:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'ajax'], function () {
    Route::get('page', 'AjaxController@page')->name('ajax.page');
});
```

But i Get issue with that routing, sometimes ajax doesnt work or other router doesnt work neither... but if i delete the prefix => {slug} and I put something like prefix => "test/{slug}" everything works perfectly.

Who i can make the two routers works?

Thansk

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/{slug}', 'namespace' => 'User'], function () {
  Route::group(['prefix' => 'ajax'], function () {
    Route::get('/page', 'AjaxController@page');
  });
});
```

Comment: But i don't want url as "{slug}/ajax/page"... 

i want 
{slug}/whatever
ajax/whatever
other/whatever

... etc, buf if doesnt exist any other, take {slug}... it's possible?

Comment: use `{slug}/{param1?}/{param2?}`